# What is the Regex for /\bbad|\bwords/gi in C#?

Tags: c#, regex

https://regex101.com/r/oE4nG5/5

I want to know this Regex pattern for C#. The pattern I just linked is for Javascript. `/\bbad|\bwords/gi`
I want to use the pattern like so: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/vQhJk9

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string [] flame = {
            "bad", "words", "inc"
        };
        string argsInput = "some bad ";
        //Regex regex = new Regex(@"\bad|\words|\inc");
        var sjoin = string.Join("|\\b", flame);
        Regex regex = new Regex ("@\"" + sjoin + "\"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        Console.WriteLine(sjoin);
        Match match = regex.Match(argsInput);
        if (match.Success) {
            Console.WriteLine("success");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like below.

- You don't need to match double quotes, since the input strings won't contain any double quotes. `"bad"` represents `bad` is a string not a variable.

**Code:**

```
string [] flame = {
    "bad", "words", "inc"
};
string argsInput = "some bad ";
//Regex regex = new Regex(@"\bad|\words|\inc");
var sjoin = string.Join("|\\b", flame);

Regex regex = new Regex ( sjoin , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Console.WriteLine(sjoin);
Match match = regex.Match(argsInput);
if (match.Success) {
    Console.WriteLine("success");
}
```

[DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9EkFEE)

Comment: ya, it's not necessary.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/b9U6jI i made a better example. these words have to stay alone. i dont want them to match when the word is part of another word.